# Where is the argument coming from?

Tags: function, lambda, arguments, racket, programming-languages

**You can notice the v in the lambda in the function body, where is the v coming from, what it is based on?**

```
(define (cached-assoc xs n)
  (letrec ([memo (make-vector n #f)]
           [acc 0]
           [f (lambda(x)
                (let ([ans (vector-assoc x memo)])
                  (if ans
                      (cdr ans)
                      (let ([new-ans (assoc x xs)])
                       (begin
                         (vector-set! memo acc (cons x new-ans))
                         (set! acc (if (= (+ acc 1)) 0 (+ acc 1)))
                         new-ans)))))])
  (lambda (v) (f v))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole expression is returning a `lambda` as a result, and in that `lambda` there's a formal parameter named `v`. It doesn't have a value yet, you'll need to *call* the `lambda` to bind a value to `v` and produce a result (assuming the code is working):

```
((letrec ([memo (make-vector n #f)] ; notice the extra opening `(`, we want to call the returned lambda
          [acc 0]
          [f (lambda(x)
               (let ([ans (vector-assoc x memo)])
                 (if ans
                     (cdr ans)
                     (let ([new-ans (assoc x xs)])
                       (begin
                         (vector-set! memo acc (cons x new-ans))
                         (set! acc (if (= (+ acc 1)) 0 (+ acc 1)))
                         new-ans)))))])
   (lambda (v) (f v)))
 10) ; <- the value 10 gets bound to `v`
```

However, your code isn't right. You are referring to variables named `n` and `xs`, but they are not defined anywhere and need a value of their own. The procedure `vector-assoc` doesn't exist. Also, the `lambda` at the end is redundant, you could simply return `f`, there's no need to wrap it in an additional `lambda`. Finally: you should `define` the whole expression with a name, it'll make it easier to call it.

I won't go into more details because first you need to fix the function and make it work, and is not clear at all what you want to do - but that should be a separate question.

Comment: you are right, i wrote it wrong here, I've fixed it now, I hope you can review it now.

Comment: @Amen but I already answered your question :) the procedure returns another procedure, the v is not bound inside this procedure, it’ll only get a value from “outside” when you invoke it. If you need further help fixing the procedure itself please post a new question explaining what you want it to do, including sample input and expected output.